# Glyphicons in Bootstrap 3 don't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webforms, glyphicons

I know this question has been asked before, but can't find anything specific on how to solve my issue.

I did a previous MVC project where the glyph icons are working just fine.

I'm in another project where it's not working. However, this project I'm taking over from somebody else is a **web forms** project. I took a look at the source code and the span tags are there for the icons, but they don't show up on the buttons. It also seems that everything is in place.

The icons for the glyphs are present in the fonts directory.

### Can someone please let me know what I might be missing?

Edit: Posting code where glyphicons don't show up.

Here is the code for the two buttons, "**Stop**" & "**Penalize**".

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnStop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>Stop</button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnPenalize"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>Penalize</button>

                                            </div>
```

Here is the screenshot of the two buttons which don't show the glyphicons:
[image]

---

Edit #2 - Buttons with Firefox
[image]

You can see in the first image is with IE. In the second image you can see that the glyph icons try to appear in Firefox, but just empty squares.

Here is the masterpage code as far as all the links go...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/ace-fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/ace.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/ace-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/assets/css/ace-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-switch/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <%--<link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/styling-02.css" rel="stylesheet" />--%>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <%--<link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />--%>
    <link rel="../content/lib/assets/css/ace-skins.min.css" />
    <link rel="../content/lib/assets/css/ace-rtl.min.css" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/js-css-menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/js-css-menu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <!-- page specific plugin styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/assets/css/datepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/assets/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style3
        {
            left: 0px;
            top: 7px;
        }
    </style>
<%-- main page styling  --%>
    <link href="../Content/ryder/css/ryder.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootbox3/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ryder/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ryder/hidden-navs.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/ryder/telerik-controls.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/grid.locale-en.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/assets/js/ace-extra.min.js"></script>

    <%--<script src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/lib/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/Common.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/DataServices/StopPenalize.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/DataServices/CreditSourceDocs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet illustrating one of the icons not working?

Comment: You have the directory structure different from where the fonts should be. The css is using a relative path "../fonts/" your bootstrap.min.css file is looking for one level up and inside the fonts directory, you have many levels out before the font directory

Comment: khilley, I posted the code and screenshot where glyphicons are not showing up in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the link to /fonts, also have you tried testing it in antoher explorer?

Comment: Can you post how are you using the glyphicon?

Comment: Esteban, I posted the code and screenshot where glyphicons are not showing up in my edit.

Comment: In my MVC application which works fine, there is no link in the bundleconfig file for the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

When downloading bootstrap you should have also downloaded a folder named fonts. You must be missing that, because that's what solved the problem with my page. The folder 'fonts' should be in the main directory of your page. I hope this solves your problem.